# How to create an Akka Stream Flow that pauses until a flag is lowered?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I want to create an Akka Streams Flow that will consume an element and hold it until a Flag is lowered.

The desired effect is illustrated below but I realise that this not a good solution.

```
val flow: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] = {
     Flow[Int] map { i =>
       if (flagIsRaised) { waitUntilFlagIsLowered(); i}
       else { i }
     }
}
```

For example, I don't want `waitUntilFlagIsLowered` to block.

Ideally, I would like an idiomatic Akka Streams solution that might be possible using [standard Akka Streams operators](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/index.htm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [`Valve`](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/api/akka-stream-contrib/current/akka/stream/contrib/Valve.html) utility from the [Akka Streams Contrib](https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib) project:

> Materializes into a Future of [ValveSwitch](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/api/akka-stream-contrib/current/akka/stream/contrib/ValveSwitch.html) which provides a the method flip that stops or restarts the flow of elements passing through the stage. As long as the valve is closed it will backpressure.

Examples of how to use it are in [`ValveSpec`](https://github.com/akka/akka-stream-contrib/blob/v0.10/src/test/scala/akka/stream/contrib/ValveSpec.scala).

Comment: Thank you very much, Jeffrey!  I'll check that out.
I'll leave the question unanswered for the weekend to allow time for any other answers.